# there was an error attaching the debugger to the role instance

Tags: azure, window

I am getting an Exception when I am trying debug my application on Emulator (Web Role).

you can see exception by clicking following [link](http://s14.postimage.org/cotqvp7dd/142058.jpg)

Configuration which I am using Windows 7 pro, VS 2012 Pro, Azure SDK 1.8

Answer (score 3):

Hope it might help others.

I Also had the similar problem and I restarted PC and `**Run Visual Studio as Administrator**`.
And let Visual Studio start the emulator with same privilege resolved the issue.

I was using Visual 2013 and Web API application under IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IIS added? Most likely it's already installed but you've to enable it via Add Windows Compoenents on Control Panel...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue all of a sudden, luckly I remember changing the ServiceDefinition.csdef file.  I rolled this back to an earlier version and the debugger ran again correctly.  The only thing I changed in the 'broken' version was instance size from small to medium.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Go to visual studio installer**(search it from window's start)
   and **update the visual studio**.
2. After updating, **hit modify
   button**, after that on right side you will **find a box named
   debug** (or something like that), **select that box**
3. Then **hit install**.
4. **Restart** your visual studio and debugger will start working.

In my case it worked perfectly.